# Dropdown menu under item (not beside) on vertical main menu

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm building a responsive Semantic UI `vertical menu`. On big screens it's a sidebar and on small screens it's a full width menu. Now there is an `dropdown item` in it with a submenu.

On a small screen: How to show the submenu below the menu item?

In this example you can click the Item and the submenu is hidden right off the screen:
https://jsfiddle.net/mb0mtnmj/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are probably looking for is to change the menu direction. You can use the `left` class on the menu div so that it doesn't flow off screen. See https://jsfiddle.net/mb0mtnmj/6/

You can also find more info here https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: Oh, yes! Not perfect but usable. Thanks.